# How to change font size for clock in top bar (GTK)

Tags: gnome-shell, gtk, 19.04

I am on 19.04. If it is not possible to change the font only for the clock, I would like to change the font size for the entire top bar. I have tried changing "stage" in gnome-shell.css and also the TOP BAR section, but the font size remains the same in my bar. I have found other answers here that answer this question but those answers refer to older versions and do not refer to GTK, and so don't work.

I do not want to change the font of everything else as would happen by setting "large text" in accessibility, or using the scaling slider in tweak tool. I am curious if there is another way to do this besides creating a custom CSS override for the shell theme. I only want to enlarge the time (as I cannot see it), and if that is not possible, only the top bar.

Comment: That post probably leads to what I'm looking for, but I cannot find ".clock-display" in my gnome-shell.css. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I am using Gnome Classic, not Ubuntu

Comment: Hi, sorry had to step out for a bit. Your fix works perfectly if I use Ubuntu desktop, but not in Gnome classic. In gnome classic, I see themes under the "appearance" tab in tweaks. I have selected Yaru, but my shell says "default".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***for Ubuntu 19.04 default***

add this line at around line number 786, Change the values as you wish..

```
#panel .clock-display { color: yellow; text-align: center; font-size: 23pt; }
```

[image]

If you are using Gnome-Classic via Vanilla-Gnome-Desktop

edit the file gnome `gnome-classic.css` from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/-----`

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer for ubuntu desktop. I was using Gnome classic because I liked the default dock better. Now I switched to Ubuntu and figured out how to make the dock how I like it. Lovin my big clock up at the top!

Comment: Hi how to install gnome classic? how did you install? i tried installing gnome classic by googling but it did not show user themes option under tweaks..

Comment: sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop - then logout. On the login screen hit the little gear for settings and choose gnome classic for desktop. If you get the clock worked out, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: vanilla gnome desktop... oh ok.. i installed some other.. i will install it and get back to you..

Comment: There is also gnome-session-flashback but I don't remember which one i installed. Flashback is much smaller and includes much less stuff. I'm trying to work out what I did......

Comment: And I found gnome-session which is even smaller. I'm not sure how much you need for simulation.....