# Weird Time Indentation

Tags: disk-usage, time, clock

My Ubuntu has this weird time Indentation on the digital clock. Here is a picture

[image]

My Sys Info:
Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine

Comment: have you set any theme or extensions?

Comment: @PRATAP Yes I set the gnome dark theme

Comment: 0k change it to any other theme and see.. if you find difference then you can tweak dark theme..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1149341/739431 just for idea.. actual tweaking differs from the outputs you provide

Comment: @PRATAP I just changed it and it didnt do anything to the time

Comment: do you hv gnome-tweaks installed? then try changing fonts and see.

Comment: @PRATAP Yes that’s what I’m using for the themes I’m using Yaru-Dark

Comment: no.. I am telling about fonts section in tweaks..

Comment: @PRATAP I changed the font and it didn’t do anything

Comment: 0k change the font style as per the link above and try but if you are starter it is risky to edit that file..

Comment: @PRATAP I tried that and it still didn’t work

Comment: seems I have to try to reproduce the issue. Yaru-Dark is the shell theme rite?

Comment: @PRATAP Yes it is Yaru-Dark